# The security token included in the request is invalid. When no profile specified

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-secrets-manager

When running this:

```
session = boto3.session.Session()
client = session.client(service_name="secretsmanager", region_name='region')
secret_response = client.get_secret_value(SecretId='secret_name')
print(secret_response)
```

This is the error that I get:
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the GetSecretValue operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.

But when I run the exact same code but specify my profile like this:

```
session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='default')
```

it works.

boto3 version: 1.27.6

Comment: Try reconfigure: `aws configure`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd actually just make sure you aren't setting your AWS_PROFILE env variable any where else, this is a common issue people have. I use this bash function whenever I need to clear all AWS related environment variables.

```bash
awskill () {
    unset AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE
    unset AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    unset AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    unset AWS_SECRET_KEY
    unset AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN
    unset AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is it! I work on Windows and I had to remove AWS related environment variables, create a new config in Pycharm and restart Pycharm.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have mulitple profiles in `aws credentials`. Whats baffling is that even if you use `boto3.session.Session()` without specifying a profile, it's supposed to use the `default` profile.

However, try to remove `aws credentials` first by running `rm ~/.aws/credentials`. After that, run `aws configure` again and follow the prompt to add your credentials properly. This should solve the problem.